# TypeErrors: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable +'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, minimize

I am new in coding and I don't know how to do to fix these problems. The first error shows up in step1 where says; ''TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable''. This goes away when I remove the sum from add_diff_sq in function f(), but I need this sum there.

The second error comes in step2 "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable". Is this error because x, y and z are tuples? How can I solve this?

data_test01.csv file contains data with 3 columns, x, y ,z.

Thanks

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import glob
import cv2

#Fitting function============================================================

def f():
    '''Process of constructing a curve that has the best fit to a series of 
    data points'''


    fit_x = x1+Rz*np.cosh((1/Rz)*(y-y1-(z/2))) 
    x_sq = (x-x1)**2
    y_sq = Rz**2-(y-y1)**2
    diff_sq = (x-(x1+Rz*np.cosh((1/Rz)*(y-y1-(z/2)))))**2
    add_diff_sq = sum(x-(x1+Rz*np.cosh((1/Rz)*(y-y1-(z/2)))))**2


    return fit_x, x_sq, y_sq, diff_sq, add_diff_sq

#Initial guesses============================================================== 

x1 = 19.783
y1 = 20.647
Rz = 2.884

guesses = [x1, y1, Rz]

#Open file====================================================================

with open('data_test01.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        x = float(row[0])
        y = float(row[1])
        z = float(row[2])

#Step 1=======================================================================

        fit_x, x_sq, y_sq, diff_sq, add_diff_sq = f()
        '''First fitting approximation'''
        print(f())



TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable


#Step 2=======================================================================

res = minimize(f(), guesses, method='SLSQP')
'''Minimizes the objective function to achieve a better fit'''
print(res)



TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: Well, the initial guesses are supposed to be an ndarray, not a list. And, the function you are trying to minimize does not take any parameters, which is really confusing to scipy...

Comment: Thanks for your replay Jon. I will change this.